# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'app' of undefined Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, single-page-application

I wanted to setup a SPA using Laravel 5.4 and Vue2. I have following a tutorial (Jeffrey Way - Laracast). But i am getting this issue. Can not figure it out why this error in console?? :

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'app' of undefined
    at VueRouter (app.js:3149)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:4266)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:3343)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:13749)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:66
    at app.js:69
```

Here is my code below :

app.js

```
import router from './routes';

import './bootstrap';

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    router
});
```

routes.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: require('./views/Home')
        }
    ];

export default VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

bootstrap.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';

window.Vue = Vue;
window.axios = axios;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

Comment: We can't help without code.

Comment: Cold you provide your code for tracing the error?

Comment: @str i have pasted the code here.. take a look

Comment: @Wei code is here now

Comment: I can't find 'app' in here, can you find snippet like var app = new Vue({})

Comment: u can see at app.js @myke_11j

Comment: @WahidSherief, The error stack show the error occurs in app.js:69. What is the code at the line? Besides, is the #root element well prepared in DOM?

Comment: @Wei app.js only 8 lines .. yes i assigned <div id='root'>

Comment: Well, because app.js was packaged by webpack, can you trace it on browser when you execute it by setting a breaking point, and It may find out the line of this error occur.

Comment: i dont know how to do that @Wei .. i am new at vue.js

Comment: Try this with chrome (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints)

Answer (score 12):

```
export default new VueRouter({
  routes
});
```

add "new"

Answer (score 0):

```
let routes = [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: require('./views/Home')
        }
    ];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```